# Apex equivalent to Javascript For In

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a variable that contains a list of account objects and I want to iterate through all of the fields of those accounts.

I am able to accomplish this through javascript using the below code, but I don't want to take things out of apex if I don't have to.

Does apex have an equivalent to Javascript's "IN" that would allow me to compare all fields to the same field in the next record like below?

```
for (var key in dataGet.accounts[i]) {
     if (dataGet.accounts[i][key] != dataGet.accounts[i+1][key]) {
     dataGet.accounts[i][key] = dataGet.accounts[i+1][key];
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all fields populated in one record as a key => value kind of access you can use [`accounts[i].getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

To compare all fields on 2 objects (whether they're populated or not) you should read up on "Dynamic Apex" and "[describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm)" operations. Something like this will get you all API names on the object:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();
```

And then you can iterate on the map keys

```
for(String field : fieldsMap.keyset()){
    System.debug(field + ': ' + accounts[i].get(field));
}
```

---

If you don't work with sObjects but with some classes which you can't control (meaning you can't just change internal implementation to use `Map<String, String>` to store key-value pairs or something)... This could work. Apex doesn't have reflection.

```
public with sharing class Stack47339633{
    public String name, some, other, property;
    public Integer someInt;
    public Date d;
}

Stack47339633 obj1 = new Stack47339633();
obj1.name = 'hello';
obj1.some = 'world';
obj1.someInt = 13;
obj1.d = System.today();

Stack47339633 obj2 = new Stack47339633();
obj2.name = 'hello';
obj2.some = 'stackoverflow';
obj2.someInt = -7;
obj2.d = System.today();

// Let's treat them as JSON objects...
Map<String, Object> o1 = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(obj1));
Map<String, Object> o2 = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(obj2));
Map<String, Object> o3 = new Map<String, Object>();

// ...compare, write identical fields to result object
for(String s : o1.keyset()){
    System.debug(s + ':' + o1.get(s) + ' == ' + o2.get(s) + '?');
    if(o1.get(s) == o2.get(s)){
        System.debug('match!');
        o3.put(s, o1.get(s));
    }
}

// and cast that result object back to real class instance
Stack47339633 obj3 = (Stack47339633) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(o3), Stack47339633.class);
System.debug('Full result: ' + obj3);
System.debug('Name : ' + obj3.name);
System.debug('someint : ' + obj3.someInt);
System.debug('d : ' + obj3.d);
```

It's not pretty with all this casting to JSON and back but it gets the job done.
There will be situations where serialization can fail (for example holding references to `this`), if something is marked as `transient` it might not survive... But I don't think you'll have better option.

Check also these:

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135891/can-we-access-class-properties-dynamically-with-object-class
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16780/how-to-get-the-attribute-class-list

Comment: Thanks!

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the strings of these objects though. 

Let's say this is not the account object, but a custom external class that has the string attributes. So dataGet would be the class and name would be the string.

EX: if (accts[i].get(field) = 3 { accts[i+1].get(field) = 'NUM3' }. The error I receive is that I cannot set the expression which I understand, but how would I reference that field in a way that it would represent dataGet.name?